# QApplication child objects not destroyed when the system is shut down

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application with a single dialog window. The main looks like this:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MyObject * myMobject = new QObject(&a);
MainWindow w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

`MyObject` constructor creates a temporary file, and the destructor deletes it.

When I close the application normally by closing the dialog, `MyObject` destructor is called as expected, as it is a child of `QApplication`, which is allocated on the stack in `main()`.

However, when the user session is closed (log off, shutdown, ...), the file is not removed, showing that `MyObject` destructor is never called.

What is the reason for this? I though that Windows was closing every window before session shutdown, but it looks like my process is terminated.

From the documentation, there is the `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()` signal. But this documentation tells that Qt detects the shutdown and exits the event loop, emitting that signal at the very end.

If that's really the case, `a.exec()` should return, exactly like when the window is closed, and the `QApplication` should be destroyed with its children, calling `MyObject` destructor. In other words, as `myObject` is a child of `a`, there should not be any need to handle the `aboutToQuit()` signal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195935/how-to-detect-windows-shutdown-or-logoff-in-qt

Comment: I have added some information at the end about this. The other post does not answer the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from QApplication's documentation:

> We recommend that you connect clean-up code to the aboutToQuit() signal, instead of putting it in your application's main() function. This is because, on some platforms the QApplication::exec() call may not return. For example, on the Windows platform, when the user logs off, the system terminates the process after Qt closes all top-level windows. Hence, there is no guarantee that the application will have time to exit its event loop and execute code at the end of the main() function, after the QApplication::exec() call.

Comment: Damn, I'm RTFM'd. They could have added this to aboutToQuit() though